# Find $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2m-1)!!}{2^m \, m! \, m^{n+1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the value of
$$
S(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2m-1)!!}{2^m \, m! \, m^{n+1}}
$$
where $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to $0$. Mathematica can do individual cases, $S(0) = \ln(4)$ for example, but it can't do the general case.

Comment: I think it is useful to notice that $$\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2m)!\,x^m}{4^m(m!)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$$

Comment: Mathematica also gives $S(1)=\zeta(2)-2\log^2(2)$, $S(2)=-2\zeta(2)\log(2)+\frac{4}{3}\log^3(2)+2\zeta(3)$.

Comment: And $$\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2m)!\,x^m}{4^m (m!)^2 m^{n+1}}=\frac{x}{2}\phantom{}_{n+3} F_{n+2}\left(1,1,\ldots,\frac{3}{2};2,2,\ldots,x\right).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I have an answer that supports my initial feelings: $S(n)$ can be handled through polygamma identities (see $(4)$ and $(5)$). We have:

$$ S(n) = \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\binom{2m}{m}\frac{1}{4^m m^{n+1}}, $$
and, for any $x\in(0,1)$,
$$ f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\binom{2m}{m}\frac{x^{m-1}}{4^m} = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x}}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{1-x})\cdot\sqrt{1-x}}\tag{1}.$$
Using now the identity:
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-1}\log^n(x)\,dx=\frac{n!}{m^{n+1}}\tag{2}$$
we can state:
$$S(n)=\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\log^n(x)\,dx =\frac{2}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^n(1-u^2)}{1+u}\,du\tag{3}$$
but we can see the LHS also as:
$$S(n)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\ldots\frac{\partial}{\partial a_n}\left.\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cdot x^{\sum a_i}dx\right)\right|_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(0^+,\ldots,0^+)},\tag{4}$$
but since:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx = B(1/2,k) = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\cdot\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(k+1/2)}\tag{5}$$
we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,x^{\sum a_i}dx = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\cdot\Gamma(\sum a_i)}{\Gamma(1/2+\sum a_i)}-\frac{1}{\sum a_i}=g\left(\sum a_i\right).\tag{6}$$
By $(4)$ and $(6)$, now we can read any $S(n)$ in the Taylor series coefficients of 
$$ g(x) = \frac{2^{2x}\Gamma(x)^2}{2\cdot\Gamma(2x)}-\frac{1}{x}$$ 
or
$$ x\cdot g(x) = \frac{2^{2x}\Gamma(x+1)^2}{\Gamma(2x+1)}-1 \tag{7}$$
around $x=0$. By the Weierstrass product for the Gamma function we know that:
$$ \log\Gamma(z+1)=-\gamma z+\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{k}(-z)^k, \tag{8}$$
and by $(7)$:
$$ x\cdot g(x) = -1+\exp\left(2x\log 2+2\log\Gamma(x+1)-\log\Gamma(2x+1)\right),$$
$$ x\cdot g(x) = -1+\exp\left(2x\log 2-2\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)(2^k-1)}{k}(-z)^k\right).\tag{9}$$
This gives that we can compute $S(n)$ by exponentiating a relatively simple Taylor series whose coefficients are $\log(4)$ and rational multiples of the values of the Riemann zeta function in the integers greater than one.

Comment: I am not mixing anything, I am using the fact that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-1}\log^n(x)\,dx= \frac{n!}{m^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: My bad. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!